# Maximum checked allow in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have generated a CheckBoxList which has more than one item using C#. Now I want to set a maximum number of checked item allowed in CheckBoxList. If user check more than maximum allowed item, there will be an alert or the other item will automatic uncheck to prevent user check over maximum number of item allowed.

The maximum number of checked item will be set up to ChecokBoxList in code-behind (C#) or using javascript do this, but the javascript is also should be generated in C# too.

I need some help to solve this issue.

Example Code:

```
CheckBoxList chkl = new CheckBoxList();
string[] items = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"};
foreach (string item in items )
            {
                chkl.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
            }
chkl.MaximumCheck = 3;
```

After generated in code-behind, the CheckBoxList will only allow user to check only three items. If user check more than three item, other item will automatic uncheck or at least an alert will show to prevent user check more than three items.

Comment: If an attempt is made to check a fourth item, there will be an alert show to user that they cannot do more check, or the fourth check cannot made because that item is disable.

Comment: I will try to write a code in C# using post-back to do this if whenever user check on any item on checkboxlist. I will show you later for further help in my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0;
foreach (var li in ListBox1.Items) {
 if (li.Selected == true)
 {
  x = x + 1;
 }
```

or like:

```
ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices().Length
```

In Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function CheckCheck()
{
    var chkBoxList=document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');        var chkBoxCount=chkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");

     var btn=document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>');
     var i=0;
     var tot=0;
     for(i=0;i<chkBoxCount.length;i++)
     {
      if(chkBoxCount[i].checked)
      {
       tot=tot+1;
      }
     }

if(tot > 3)
{
   alert('Cannot check more than 3 check boxes');              
}    
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck();">
<asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is what I want, because there is no need to do post-back event on checked. But there is some thing miss my target, dynamic controls much have different ID and how javascript can recognize which checkbolist is going to call it? And how it know the maximum check attribute of any individual checkboxlist if they call it?

Comment: My own answer has solve this issue, but it require a post-back event. And that is what I am going to avoid because I am adding dynamic control to an updatepanel. So any post-back can be destroy the current view-state of aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a good solution for this issue:

In C# I will generate a CheckBoxList with 5 items using this code:

```
CheckBoxList chkl = new CheckBoxList();
    string[] items = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" };
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        chkl.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
    }
    chkl.AutoPostBack = true;
    chkl.CssClass = "3";
    chkl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(BoxChecked);
```

As you can see, the CheckBoxList has 5 item and the maximum checked item is seted via CssClass attribute of CheckBoxList, assumed there will be no CssClass needed in CheckBoxList. So that I will set the maximum checked item via this attribute to make it more clear. The key here is to add an EventHandler on CheckboxList, so that if user going to check more than the maximum item, other item will be disable.

The EventHander will be written as follow:

```
protected void BoxChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int maximumCheck = -1;
        CheckBoxList CheckExpertiseList = (CheckBoxList)sender;
        try {
            maximumCheck = Convert.ToInt32(CheckExpertiseList.CssClass);
        }
        catch { }
        if (maximumCheck > -1)
        {
            if (CheckExpertiseList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => (i.Selected == true)).Count() == maximumCheck)
            {
                CheckExpertiseList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => (i.Selected == false)).ToList().ConvertAll(i => i.Enabled = false).ToList();
            }
            else if (CheckExpertiseList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => (i.Selected == true)).Count() == maximumCheck - 1)
                CheckExpertiseList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => (i.Selected == false)).ToList().ConvertAll(i => i.Enabled = true).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

EventHandler Event will check if the checkboxlist has over limit item checked it will disable other items, else it will reenable other item.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am thank you to Jeremy Thompson. He gave me a good idea for my issue. A little bit change and I have what I want. Solve my issue only using javascript.

```
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function CheckCheck() {
        var chkBoxCount = this.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var max = parseInt(this.className);
        var i = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
                tot = tot + 1;
            }
        }

        if (tot > max) {
            var k = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
                if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
                    k++;
                    if (k > max) {
                        chkBoxCount[i].checked = false;
                        alert('Cannot check more than ' + max + ' check boxes');
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
</script>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="3" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck.call(this);">
<asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript will automatic recognize what control is going to call it, and it also get the maximum check item via attribute CssClass of control. By doing this, I also prevent user check more than maximum item in CheckBoxList without doing some post-back.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cb_magia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int maxNumber = 4;
        int iSelectedIndex = cb_magia.SelectedIndex;
        if (cb_magia.CheckedItems.Count > maxNumber)
        {
           cb_magia.SetItemCheckState(iSelectedIndex, CheckState.Unchecked);
           MessageBox.Show("you had checked the maximum checkbox value allowed");

        }
    }
```